# Magento 2 Chaning Storeview not chaning category and product url key

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento 2 store with two store views ( one english one italian ).

But, I encounter a problem when switching between store views when I'm inside a category or a product.

The Url key won't change. Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to enable sessionId from admin, it should work after it

Answer (score 0):

You can change the category url for specific storeview from the backend category page itself.

> 1. Admin-> Dashboard -> Catalog -> Categories -> Edit any of them -> switch store -> Search Engine Optimization-> change the url.
> 2. Please flush cache then.

Please find the screenshot added for this.
[image]

You can also change the product url for specific stores

> 1. Admin-> Dashboard -> Catalog -> Product -> Edit any of them -> switch store -> Search Engine Optimization-> change the url.
> 2. Please flush cache then.

scrrenshot attached below.

[image]

Comment: Yes i have changed all the categories url key for each store view but they won't change when switching ..  how can i remake all the urls ?

Comment: Please check after flush magento cache and browser cache